# StreamCorrupedException occurs when readObject

Tags: java, exception, header, stream, redis

hi I need to read byte arrays as an Object. however whenever I try it prints out Stream CorruptedException.

Below is my writing code

```
public class TestSave {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String key = "redismap";
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        map.put("String", "test");
        map.put("List", list);

        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;

        JedisHelper helper = JedisHelper.getInstacne();
        Jedis connection = helper.getConnection();

        try{
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            oos.writeObject(map);
            byte[] value = bos.toByteArray();           
            oos.close();
            connection.set(key.getBytes(), value);
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        helper.returnResource(connection);
        helper.destroyPool();
        System.out.println("DONE!");
    }
}
```

then, this is read code

```
public class TestWithdaw {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JedisHelper helper = JedisHelper.getInstacne();
        Jedis connection = helper.getConnection();
        String key = "redismap";
        String result = connection.get(key);
        byte[] primalData = result.getBytes();
        System.out.println("Byte Arrays : " + Arrays.toString(primalData));

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;

        try{
            bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(primalData);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            Object resultMap = ois.readObject();

            System.out.println("resultMap : " + resultMap);
            ois.close();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        helper.returnResource(connection);
        helper.destroyPool();
    }
}
```

Then this is THE ERROR message I got.

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at org.owls.redis.test.TestWithdaw.main(TestWithdaw.java:28)
```

I can not understand what is wrong with this stream header.
these are what I tried already :-<

1. change List to Vector in writing code. (Serial problem)

Thanks for helping me :D

Comment: What happens if you call `oos.close` before `bos.toByteArray`?

Comment: `ObjectOutputStream` is buffered! You need to call `flush()` (or `close()`) _before_ retrieving the data.

Comment: @immibis same result. it still shows StreamCorruptedException.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think it does not matters, because writing has no problem. These codes work separately, but I posted input code also because it could have encoding problem.

Comment: Is there something like `connection.get(key)` that returns a byte array? Strings are not byte arrays - I just noticed you're converting your data to a string and back.

Comment: @immibis yeah. that was the main problem, I guess :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in your storage and retrieval of the serialised bytes - the code to perform the serialisation and deserialisation is itself fine.

Without the intermediate storage, the code works, as shown below:

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
  oos.writeObject(map);
  byte[] value = bos.toByteArray();
  oos.close();

  for (byte b : value)
  {
    System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(0xff & b) + " ");
  }
  System.out.println("");

  final ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(value));
  final Object read = ois.readObject();

  System.out.println("read: " + read);
```

This produces:

> ac ed 0 5 73 72 0 11 6a 61 76 61 2e 75 74 69 6c 2e 48 61 73 68 4d 61 70 5 7 da c1 c3 16 60 d1 3 0 2 46 0 a 6c 6f 61 64 46 61 63 74 6f 72 49 0 9 74 68 72 65 73 68 6f 6c 64 78 70 3f 40 0 0 0 0 0 c 77 8 0 0 0 10 0 0 0 2 74 0 6 53 74 72 69 6e 67 74 0 4 74 65 73 74 74 0 4 4c 69 73 74 73 72 0 13 6a 61 76 61 2e 75 74 69 6c 2e 41 72 72 61 79 4c 69 73 74 78 81 d2 1d 99 c7 61 9d 3 0 1 49 0 4 73 69 7a 65 78 70 0 0 0 0 77 4 0 0 0 0 78 78
>
> read: {List=[], String=test}

You'll see that we find the beginning of the byte stream is `ac ed 00 05 73`, which are the following Java Object Serialization Specification constants:

- `STREAM_MAGIC`
- `STREAM_VERSION`
- `TC_OBJECT`

As such, you investigation should focus on why your primal data doesn't match the originally generated data.

---

Let's continue in that direction (disclaimer: I've never used Redis) ...

You get the data back from Redis using this code:

```
String key = "redismap";
String result = connection.get(key);
byte[] primalData = result.getBytes();
```

Here, you get the data back as a Java `String`, and then get the bytes using the Java VM's default encoding scheme.  This is potentially different to the encoding representation used by Redis.

Why don't you use the version that returns a `byte[]`?  That would be:

```
String key = "redismap";
byte[] primalData = connection.get(key.getBytes());
```

This is likely to be consistent in any `String` to `byte[]` encoding and decoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, I worried about character encoding set of key. However after I changed parameter from String to byte[] as you suggested, it works wonderful. Thank again :D

Comment: @greg Similar thing was happening with us when we were using ISO-8859-1 encoding with Redis data store. Finally converted everything to byte[] and all works fine now. Thanks your answer gave me few pointers to debug.